# location.href and fallback for page not available

Tags: javascript

Is there a way when I reload a page with javascript to have a fallback if the target page is not available?

**Example:**

I am doing

`location.href = 'http://www.google.com'`

But maybe google is down (or maybe the url does not exist anymore or is malformed, etc...) and in this case, I would like to avoid the reloading. Is that possible?

Comment: One tricky solution would be to make an AJAX request before and if it's succeed then navigate to the url

Comment: If it is on the same domain, you could use HEAD-request using Ajax BEFORE location.href thing..! If its not in same domain then i dont think it can be done..

Comment: I am looking for a solution for any domain (if it is possible).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't recognize what happens after a visitor leaves your page. This is a good thing. Maybe you check before the redirect, if you can connect (client side) with javascript if the website is available and then perform your redirect. But you have to check before the redirect, but not after as a fallback.

Answer (score 0):

**If it is on the same domain**, you could use HEAD-request using Ajax BEFORE `location.href`, like:

```
function doStuff() {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {  
    if(this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
        //page exists 
        location.href = "your_url_of_some_page";               
    }
    xhr.open("HEAD", address);
    xhr.send();
}
//call the function
doStuff();
```